# Validar um formulário em HTML com JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

Qual seria uma forma de **validar** o campo do texto assim que o botão for clicado?

Utilizando apenas *JavaScript*.

**Ex**:

> Se o campo **não for preenchido**, e o usuário for clicar no botão ele emite um alerta e não deixaria o formulário ser enviado e iria mostrar qual campo está em branco e faltando o preenchimento.

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Teste</legend>
    Informe seu nome: <input tpye="text" size="10">
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Validar">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: da para você colocar no seu input o required, e o campo seria  validado

Comment: Coloca um `id`nesse `<input>` e da um alert pelo javascript. Olha esse link.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: Se achou a resposta útil, não deixe de marcar ✔

Answer (score 3):

Simples verificação usando somente JavaScript:

```js
var formulario = document.querySelector('form');

formulario.onsubmit = function(){
   if(!document.querySelector("input[type='text']").value){
      alert("Campo nome vazio!");
      return false;
   }
   
   alert("ok");
}
```

```html
<form>
   <fieldset><legend>Teste</legend>
   Informe seu nome: <input type="text" size="10">
   <input type="submit" value="Validar">
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

#### Sugestão

Seria interessante atribuir `ids` aos elementos, como `<form id="formulario">`, ou `class` nos campos se houverem mais campos no futuro. Isso facilita a a manipulação dos elementos e no desenvolvimento do código.

Answer (score 1):

Como você pediu em JavaScript e com `alert` então ai vai. Primeiro precisará dar um `name` para o seu `input` e seu `form`, e pode fazer isso desta forma como irei mostrar abaixo.

```js
    function validar() {
    
    var nome = formulario.nome.value;
 
      if (nome == "") {
        alert('Preencha o campo com seu nome');
          formulario.nome.focus();
          return false;
       }
    }
```

```html
    <form name="formulario" action="enviar.php" method="post">
        <fieldset><legend>Teste</legend>
        Informe seu nome: <input  type="text" name='nome'>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" onclick="return validar()">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Ou simplesmente com HTML, você pode fazer isso

```html
    <form>
      <fieldset><legend>Teste</legend>
        Informe seu nome: <input  type="text" required>
        <p>
        <input type="submit">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: o jQuery é um framework, ou seja, é o próprio javascript redefinido de uma maneira mais moderna, simples de usar e  que utiliza de menos código.

Comment: resposta editada @LINQ

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `required`

Não é um pop up como você pediu, mas é bem útil para um formulário básico.

```html
<form>
<fieldset><legend>Teste</legend>
Informe seu nome: <input required tpye="text" size="10">
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Validar">
</fieldset>
</form>
```